# Provide slots to Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there any way to provide html for Vue instance? With default, named and scoped slots? Just like with components, but instead to Vue instance.

I've create a simple demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-pine-v9dkn

**main.js**

```
const compTemplate =
  '<p>main content</p><template v-slot:header="coolName">{{ coolName }}</template><template v-slot:footer>footer contnet</template>';

// How to send compTemplate to App?
new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header><slot name="header" :coolName="coolName"></slot></header>

    <slot></slot>

    <footer><slot name="footer"></slot></footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      coolName: "Some Cool Name",
    };
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you put **HTML** in a slot, then it's going to appear as plain text. You might have some close options though, depending on your use-case:

### 1. Provide the HTML as a **simple component**:

```js
Vue.component('SimpleComponent', {
  template: `
    <div
      style="font-weight: 700"
    >
      I'm formatted with HTML.
    </div>
  `
})

Vue.component('SlotContainer', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <slot name="header"></slot><br />
      <slot></slot><br />
      <slot name="footer"></slot>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `
    <slot-container>
      <template slot="header">
        header
      </template>
      <template slot="default">
        <simple-component></simple-component>
      </template>
      <template slot="footer">
        footer
      </template>
    </slot-container>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

### 2. Provide the HTML as a **prop**, not a slot:

```js
Vue.component('PropsContainer', {
  props: ['header', 'body', 'footer'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <header v-html="header"></header><br />
      <div v-html="body"></div><br />
      <footer v-html="footer"></footer>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      bodyHTML: "<strong>I'm formatted with HTML</strong>"
    }
  },
  template: `
    <props-container
      :header="'header'"
      :body="bodyHTML"
      :footer="'footer'"
    >
    </props-container>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

This one would use `v-html`, that requires extra attention because of security issues (especially, if you want to put out user input).

### 3. Compile the template on the fly

What you provided as an example is NOT a simple HTML string, it's a Vue template:

```
const compTemplate = '<p>main content</p><template v-slot:header="coolName">{{ coolName }}</template><template v-slot:footer>footer contnet</template>'
```

If you want that, then you might need a more advanced approach, you need to compile these templates runtime.

```js
const compTemplate =
  `
<div>
  <p>main content</p>
  <template v-slot:header="coolName">{{ coolName }} header content</template><br />
  <template v-slot:footer>footer content</template>
</div>
`

Vue.component('RenderComponent', {
  props: ['html'],
  render(h) {
    return h({
      template: `<div>${ this.html }</div>`
    })
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      compTemplate
    }
  },
  template: `
    <render-component
      :html="compTemplate"
    >
    </render-component>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```